# Eclipse (Weblogic workshop) problem with Projects on build path

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing this strange problem with build path with Weblogic workshop.  It's built upon Eclipse.
There is one project which needs other projects on build path.  When I add these projects on build path, everything works fine.  But when I restart Eclipse, I have to set the projects again on build path.  I have to do this everytime I restart it.
Please advise.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your project files are not read-only on disk as can happen in some source control systems. If this applies to you, check these files out first in your source control system client before making build path changes.

Comment: I am facing another problem. When I try to uncheck the read-only checkbox for a file on disk (on Windows XP OS), it's reverting it back to read-only. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: That sounds like it ought to be a separate question with windows tag perhaps?